Google Calendar API not sending emails 100% of the time
I'm using the latest version, v3, of the Google Calendar API to create events and inviting people, often outside of our organization, to these events. Some attendees never get the email that an event has been created. Some attendees get all the emails. Some get them half the time.
I am always using the following code to create the events which matches the current API Docs for doing so:
 calendarInstance.events.insert({
        calendarId: CalendarId,
        resource: event,
        conferenceDataVersion: 1,
        sendUpdates: 'all'
    }, (err, res) => { });

I have tried using the old parameter
sendNotifications: true

But no luck getting a consistent email to send when an event is created.
I've looked at other solutions but they appear out of date and the structure for the insert function is different now.
Any thoughts as to why Google might not be sending consistent emails for newly created calendar events?
UPDATE: My current latest suspicion is that this is caused by the email services blocking emails. I've tried changing the email the invitation is sent from (or, appears to send from, Google sends the email) to another one in our organization that is not a personal inbox and everyone is receiving the calendar invite emails now. Not sure if this will last forever, but we'll see and it's working for now.

How many emails are you sending at a time? It may not be an issue with the code since it's working but more on the email service itself. There are a ton of reasons as to why the emails may not be received such as the invite being marked as spam or email limits being hit.

@ShrimpFan Only 3-7 per day.

If that's the case, then it's most likely an issue with the gmail service itself. It would be better to contact Google workspace support directly so they can check as to why that's happening as it's not working as intended or file a bug following Saddle's suggestion below.

Hi, @justColbs, I see that you updated the question with the current latest suspicion is that this is caused by the email services blocking emails. It seems like changing the email where the invitation is sent from a personal inbox (@gmail.com) to an organizational one fixed the issue. If you didn't know, the reason it's working is that while personal Gmails have security protocols like SPF, DKIM, and DMARC, organizational accounts from Google Workspace often have stricter configurations, making it clearer that the emails originate from your company.

Instead of just posting that in the question, you may also post it as an answer and accept it since it worked for you. That way, other community members who stumble upon this post may know this information and how the issue was resolved.

From what I understand, the provided code is working. However, most guests in the created events are intermittently getting invites, even if sendUpdates is set to all.
I found Does not send invitation mails for events created through the "Advanced Calendar" API. on Google's Issue Tracker, which has a similar issue as yours. However, it's current status is Won't fix (Not reproducible) since the individual assigned to the ticket could not replicate the issue.
@ShrimpFan's comment also raises good points that There are a ton of reasons as to why the emails may not be received, and it could be more on the email service itself since the invite being marked as spam by the users may accidentally happen or email limits being hit. in Quotas for Google Services.
If it's confirmed that the issue is not due to what was previously mentioned and if a replication of the issue can be provided, I would recommend submitting a new bug report about the unusual behavior that's still going on.
Moreover, for further troubleshooting, you may also Contact Google Workspace support to make sure that there's no problem with your email services.
